# Open the ClearBrowserData bookmark in Chrome, in a new window

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks, javascript

I am trying to create a bookmark that will open the ClearBrowserData in Chrome in a new window, so far I have managed to get this,

```
javascript:window.open("'chrome://chrome/settings/clearBrowserData'","_blank","toolbar=no,menubar=0,status=0,copyhistory=0,scrollbars=yes,resizable=1,location=0,Width=450,Height=450") ;
```

But somehow it will not work but will open a blank window, what am I doing wrong?

Kindly note that I want this to work with one click, and not with a shortcut.

Comment: Try "_tab" instead of "_blank". Try also to [Allow all pop-ups](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95472).

Comment: Sorry mate, it didn't work

Comment: I don't have Chrome so can't test, but what about doing instead of window.open : `chrome.tabs.create({url:'chrome://settings/clearBrowserData'})` ?

Comment: Still not working :(

Comment: Then I believe that Chrome simply does not allow this in Javascript as a security feature. But let's wait and see if somebody else has more info on the subject.

Comment: @JamesYoung take a look on this page https://developer.chrome.com/stable/extensions/samples.html and http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browsingData.html

Comment: I don't want an Extension, Thanks

Comment: @harrymc right, you can't use javascript uri to run arbitrary javascript. i just tried javascript:alert('hello')

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Chrome developer has confirmed to me that this will not work as already explained in the comments earlier, and he advised me to use the [ClearBrowserData extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clearbrowserdata/apehfighfmpoieeniallefdeibodgmmb).

Comment: Then the deleted answer by @daverook is correct. It currently needs 2 more undelete votes.

Comment: That answer is undeleted now.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is possible.

After tying it myself, and then reviewing [similar posts](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/143864-start-chrome-chromesettingsclearbrowserdata/) I am confident it can't be done, simply because it could be a security vunrability.

Answer (score 3):

For those that do want a shortcut it's:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> on windows

<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd> on OS X

Comment: +1 for a faster solution and using the <kbd> tag ;)

Comment: `Cmd` + `Shift` + `Backspace` on OS X

Comment: @kavun, thanks, I've added the OS X shortcut to my answer

Answer (score 1):

I've had the following URL bookmarked since I got version 23 and it works every time.

chrome://chrome/settings/clearBrowserData

Just use right-mouse-button to select "Open in new tab" or click Middle-Mouse-Button on 3-Button Mouse